# Using admin-on-rest with public routes

Tags: admin-on-rest

I´d like make a site with public routes ('/') and admin routes (/admin).
How can I do it with rest-admin!?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `Router` for distinguishing public routes from admin ones, e.g.:

```
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index}/>
            <Route path='/admin' component={YourAdmin}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Here `Index` component is you public component (e.g. homepage). And `YourAdmin` component includes `admin-on-rest`, e.g.:

```
class YourAdmin extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Admin ...>
                <Resource .../>
                <Resource .../>
                <Resource .../>
            </Admin>
        )
    }
}
```

And your admin-page can be secured with built-in `admin-on-rest` functionality.

Comment: Thanks for help Dmytro.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, don't forget it to accept it as a right answer if it really helped.